# Crystal Reports 11 - Remove HTML format on a Memo field

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

Using Crystal Reports 11, I want to report on the number of characters within a memo field.  The problem is that it is feeding through HTML from the System.

I want to remove all text that is within "<" and ">" and am having some problems doing this.

I guessed that my best way of doing this was a Replace formula, but it only seems to allow specific characters or group of characters to be replaced.  I tried the following:

Replace ({Field_Name},"","")

Basically I want to be able to remove all text within the "<>" symbols to then be able to view the remaining data.

I know that there is an option to format the field with HTML which will then display only the text, but when a count is done on the field, it still includes the HTML text in the character count.

Any help wouldbe great.

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for @ a wk. to try to remove HTML from my emails, I decided to go into system restore and went back to a date when I thought this had happened (a wk) and voila - gone! Nada! No HTML! Problem solved so easily.